# Issues creating bot services in azure and migrating bot to bot service

Tags: azure, botframework

I have 6 bots I have built for clients on different directories/subscriptions that I need to migrate due to the recent change requiring bot services, so I've been trying to get a bot service in azure made on a number of different directories/subscriptions with no luck since 2 weeks ago. The previous error was something like "ajaxExtended not supported", but that error has gone away. Now I'm getting a "ServiceError" saying "Cannot create a v2 converged app."

The other method that is recommended is migration on the bot framework portal, but that doesn't work for me either and says "Failed to find any Azure subscriptions for the current user." I'm a part of a number of different directories and I need to migrate them to specific directories, but my primary directory doesn't have a subscription attached to it.

How can I accomplish migration to bot services given my situation?

[image: Azure Bot Service Configuration]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Do you know if you have the correct permissions to create a V2 converged app? What is your Access Control (IAM) level?

Comment: How do I check that? In the "my permissions" section it says I'm an 'Owner' on both of the primary subscriptions I'm troubleshooting.

Comment: Ok I found it, yes, I'm "owner" level.

Comment: Okay great. As Jason mentioned below you also need to have access from the Azure Tenant Admin. So that means you should also be giving similar permissions from a Azure AD point of view. If you search for Azure AD in both subscriptions can you check if you have the correct permissions there as well?

Comment: I've created app services, sql server, dbs, and cognitive services on both of these subscriptions already with no issues. Do bot services require different permissions than all of these?

Comment: I believe the permissions are different. At least in some places. Did you check to see if app registrations are turned on as mentioned below?
Disregard, I see you commented below already :)

Comment: It has been verified that the app registrations were already turned on. Still not working in azure portal.

Comment: Is the app service plan you are using brand new or is it running anything else? Also, what do you see when you follow the link to the App Registration Portal?

Answer (score 1):

For the first method, a possible reason you hit this error is that their Azure tenant admin has not allowed you to create AD apps. To resolve the issue please contact your Azure tenant admin and have them grant the proper access permissions.

[image]

Second, on the portal, as a workaround for this, you may be able to add another Email as a collaborator (in the [Bot Framework portal](https://dev.botframework.com)) that is associated with the correct Azure subscription and try to migrate it using that email account in the portal.  I have not tried this but it is probably worth giving a shot.

Comment: Ok I'll see if I can get confirmation on my azure ad settings from the tenant admins for each directory. The second option really isn't a feasible option.

Comment: It has been verified that the app registrations were already turned on. Still not working in azure portal.

Comment: @echamberlain1 If you are a guest of the tenant (azure active directory), also check that under "External Users", that "Guest users permissions are limited" is set to "NO"